# Are web.config files always valid XML?

Tags: .net, asp.net, xml, web-config

I know that the web.config parser within ASP.net is not a proper XML parser and fails on some valid XML constructs, but I wonder if the reverse is true:

Are (valid) web.config files always valid XML Files and thus readable by an XML parser?

(I need to manipulate them programatically and would prefer to use XPath, but that requires a valid XML Document)

Comment: That's news to me that web.config files are not valid XML files.  What are you basing this assertion on?

Comment: Web.config and every other .config file must be valid XML. What makes you think not? It doesn't allow all XML namespaces, is that what you mean?

Comment: @Jacob I don't know if they are valid XML files - that's exactly my questions :) But I know that the web.config parser fails if certain self-closing tags are not self closed and there are a few other quirks (I think appSettings/add must be self closing, but I can't remember if that was the issue I had)

Comment: Jacob: He never asserted that ... that's the *question* he's asking

Comment: He said "I know that the web.config parser within ASP.net is not a proper XML parser and fails on some valid XML constructs," which is an assertion.

Comment: @Michael: please post an example that fails.

Comment: Jacob: That's stating that the *parser* is not a proper XML parser.  He's asking if the *file* must always be proper XML.  The map is not the territory.

Answer (score 6):

I've used Linq to XML, XPath, and XmlDocument on config files in the past, and there's never been an XML parsing problem unless the config file itself was bad (and in that case, the application couldn't retrieve configuration settings).

So, in short, yes, they should always be readable by an XML parser.